# JQuery .html() remove line break on IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, innerhtml

So I've been trying to decode string with .html() function in jQuery and it work really nice except on IE...

Here is the string I have:

```
&#233;&#233;&#233;\r\n&#224;&#224;&#224;
```

I want this to be:

```
ééé\r\nààà
```

and I currently get after .html() with IE:

```
ééé ààà
```

So this seems nice on FF and Chrome but on IE all linebreak are removed.
I found an article (http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0226430/innerHtmlQuirk.html) explaining the problem is with .innerHTML used by .html() function...

I'm actually surprised to not found a topic about that. Is there any solution?
Maybe do a specific function to decode that on IE?

For more here is the code:

```
var itemDescription = "&#233;&#233;&#233;\r\n&#224;&#224;&#224";
$('.feeds').find('textarea.description[ifid="' + ifid + '"]').html(itemDescription);
```

Comment: This is standard behaviour. Line breaks in HTML are completely ignored, so you need to force them manually using the `<br />` tag.

Comment: ^^ This.  Do a string replace (split & join) to change `\r\n` to `<br />` and it will behave consistently on all browsers.

Comment: Actually this is in textarea and the multiple <br> just do one linebreak unfortunately.

Comment: If it's a textarea, what happens if you use `.val()` to set the value rather than `.html()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually one solution I found is to do something like that:

```
itemDescription = itemDescription.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '________BREAK________');
var decodedDescription = $("<div>").html(itemDescription).text();
decodedDescription = decodedDescription.replace(/________BREAK________/g, '\r\n');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
 var itemDescription = "&#233;&#233;&#233;\\r\\n&#224;&#224;&#224";
```

Comment: try with plain javascript: document.getElementById(TEXTAREA_ID).innerHTML=itemDescription;