# Jquery IE8 issues with .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

Its been a struggle to get this script to work. In my IE8 and Firefox page I have characters that are not rendering on my page such as <>&"' and shows up as `&lt;&gt;&amp;&quot;&#39;`. I created the following script to fix this.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".custom_pre").each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.html($this.text());

});  
});
</script>
```

It does render the text in Firefox and IE8 but removes all my line breaks so it's just once big block of text. I was able to fix it in Firefox by simply adding white-space: pre-wrap but no good in IE8. If I remove my script the line breaks remain intact. I did a bit of research and found this threads that seems similar to my case. [JQuery .html() remove line break on IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538864/jquery-html-remove-line-break-on-ie-8)

So I tried the following suggested script.

```
itemDescription = itemDescription.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '________BREAK________');
var decodedDescription = $(".custom_pre").html(itemDescription).text();
decodedDescription = decodedDescription.replace(/________BREAK________/g, '\r\n');
```

This does not render my special characters and dosen't seem to do anything. At the moment I have TD cells containing the data and they each have a class named ".custom_pre".

Would anyone have any idea what im missing?

Comment: Let's back it up a little here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well im simply trying to render the characters <>&"' as they show up as &lt;&gt;&amp;&quot;&#39;. With the script I mentioned above it forces them to render correctly however it ignore all my line breaks. I basically am looking for a way to render those characters while retaining the linebreaks.

Comment: Can you show us the part that renders those characters? Your situation seems to suggest they're getting encoded twice.

Comment: Hi Halcyon, at the moment this data is pulled from SharePoint 2007 and because is obsolete its hard to find support on it. This is why i went to Jquery for a solution. Unfortunately I don't have access to the server end to see how the first encoding happens. Worst case ill just for for a wrokaround which will be for jquery to manually replace the characters "&lt;&gt;&amp;&quot;&#39;" or to simply remove them.

Comment: Ended up fixing my issue by following this article. http://logicflowau.blogspot.ca/2009/08/sharepoint-xslt-data-view-issues_1789.html This is a SharePoint fix at this point and no longer a jquery fix.